# how can this random scene code run well when it is reloaded?

Tags: c#, random, scenemanager

I have a code for random scenes, the scenes that I have are 10 randomized scenes, but when I reload the scene there is only one scene.

```
public static int pointAdd;
// save numbers that will be random
private List<int> myNiceNumbers = new List<int>();
// the name of the scene will appear
private List<string> sceneNames = new List<string>() { "GameDD10", "GameDD20", "GameDD30", "GameDD40"};

private void Awake()
{
    // the object goes on while changing the scene
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}

private void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        myNiceNumbers.Add(i);
    }
}

public void NextScene()
{
    if (myNiceNumbers.Count != 0)
    {
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, myNiceNumbers.Count);
        int randomNumber = myNiceNumbers[randomIndex];

        myNiceNumbers.RemoveAt(randomIndex);

        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneNames[randomNumber]);
    }
    else
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("GameDDComplete");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the Game Dev Stack Exchange. I've attempted to translate your comments into English - if I've made any errors, please edit to make corrections.

Comment: When are you calling NextScene()?